# Magento 2 get custom Product Attribute from shipping

Tags: attributes, magento2

In the Carrier Model, pulling the products works via `$request->getAllItems()` and then getting the Product `$item->getProduct()`. 
I can't seem to figure out **how to pull a custom product attribute.**

```
    $item->getProduct()->getAttribute('custom_attr'); // nothing 
    $item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attr'); // uses up 3GB memory and dies 
    $item->getProduct()->getCustomAttributes(); //empty array  
    $item->getProduct()->getExtensionAttributes(); //empty array
```

also tried creating the extension_attributes.xml

Answer (score 2):

found it, finally :) Not sure if there is a better way as to load the whole product but works for now.

```
     $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());  
     $attr = $_product->getData('attribute_name');
```