# How can I get Product Custom Attribute in custom shipping module (Magento 2)?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2, custom-attributes

I am trying to fetch the product custom attribute to my custom shipping module. But unable to do so.
I tried various questions from forum but my issue still not resolved.
[question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150155/get-product-attribute-value/174402#174402): [Magento 2 get custom Product Attribute from shipping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268388/magento-2-get-custom-product-attribute-from-shipping/43972168#43972168)

But nothing works.
I create a custom attribute with the name : volweight
My File is placed in
app\code{MODULE_name}\CustomShipping\Model\Carrier\Custom.php

```
$id = 5;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
$productweight  =   $product->getData('volweight');
$this->logger->debug('PID: ', $productweight);
```

Logger I used to check my answer are correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item){
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $product->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
            
            $attribute = $product->getData('attribute_code'));
}
```